# How to access facter GCE metadata

Tags: puppet, google-compute-engine, facter

Facter contains GCE (Google Compute Engine) metadata details:

```
$ facter | grep gce
gce => {"instance"=>{"attributes"=>{}, "description"=>"", "disks"=>[{"deviceName"=>"srvpup01", "index"=>0, "mode"=>"READ_WRITE", "type"=>"PERSISTENT"}, {"deviceName"=>"srvpup01-storage01", "index"=>1, "mode"=>"READ_WRITE", "type"=>"PERSISTENT"}], "hostname"=>"srvpup01.c.example.internal", "id"=>12345, "image"=>nil, "licenses"=>[{"id"=>"1000010"}], "machineType"=>"n1-standard-1", "maintenanceEvent"=>"NONE", "networkInterfaces"=>[{"accessConfigs"=>[{"externalIp"=>"", "type"=>"ONE_TO_ONE_NAT"}], "forwardedIps"=>[], "ip"=>"123.456.789.123", "ipAliases"=>[], "mac"=>"00:11:22:33:44:55", "network"=>"example"}], "scheduling"=>{"automaticRestart"=>"TRUE", "onHostMaintenance"=>"MIGRATE", "preemptible"=>"FALSE"}, "serviceAccounts"=>{"12345-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"=>{"aliases"=>["default"], "email"=>"12345-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com", "scopes"=>["xxx"]}, "default"=>{"aliases"=>["default"], "email"=>"12345-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com", "scopes"=>["xxx"]}}, "tags"=>["no-public-ip"], "zone"=>"europe-west1-d"}, "project"=>{"attributes"=>{"google-compute-default-region"=>"europe-west1", "google-compute-default-zone"=>"europe-west1-d", "sshKeys"=>["...
```

Is there any easy way accessing like for example the "zone" attribute from within a puppet module or do I have to parse that string by myself?

Accessing it like a hash fails:

```
gce is not a hash or array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `gce is not a hash or array` suggests you're on Puppet 3.x (rather than 4.x) which treats all facts as strings, so to access the value inside the hash you will need to turn *off* the [`stringify_facts` setting](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/reference/configuration.html#stringifyfacts).

This can be done in puppet.conf on all of your agents with:

```
stringify_facts = false
```

You should then be able to access the value using:

```
$gce["zone"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the facter command line can print out the value of a nested fact like gce.zone, so you probably will need to parse it.

Note a couple of things:

1. You can pass the name of the top-level fact on the command line so it only prints that out: `facter gce` will print just the hash without the "gce =>" prefix, or need to grep.
2. You can output the fact in JSON or YAML formats to make it easier to parse.

Using [jgrep](http://jgrep.org/) you could do:

```
facter --json gce | jgrep -s gce.zone
```

or using YAML and Ruby you could do:

```
facter --yaml gce | ruby -ryaml -e 'p YAML.load(STDIN)["gce"]["zone"]'
```

or using YAML and awk:

```
facter --yaml gce | awk '/zone:/ { print $2 }'
```

Comment: OK sorry, I didn't phrase my question specific enough. That facter output was just to visualize the structure of that fact. Instead of command line, I'm trying to access that fact from within a Puppet module, but whatever I do, it either just returns the whole gce structure or exits with "gce is not a hash or array"

Comment: Ah, I posted another answer about Puppet (3.x I presume).